# How are arguments added to GraphQL, do they need to be defined before?

Tags: graphql, arguments

Hi Everyone I am just trying to learn graphql as I am using Gatsby. I want to know does each field in graphql take an argument or does it need to be defined somehow before. So for example if you visit this link [graphql search results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tnjpa.png)

https://graphql.org/swapi-graphql?query=%7B%0A%09allPeople%20%7B%0A%09%20%20people%20%7B%0A%09%20%20%20%20id%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20name%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20birthYear%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20eyeColor%0A%09%20%20%7D%0A%09%7D%0A%7D%0A

If i wanted to limit people by eye color how would I do that. In the docs it seems easy as you would just do something like `people(eyecolor: 'brown')` but that doesn't seem possible. Am I missing something? I basically want to do a SQL style search for all people where eye color is brown.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arguments need to be defined in the schema and implemented in the resolver. If you're consuming a 3rd party API (like the link you provided), you're limited to their schema. You can tell by looking at their schema (by clicking `Docs` on the right side of the page) which fields take arguments. For example, `person` takes `id` and `personID` arguments:

[image: person(id: ID, personID: ID): Person]

`people` doesn't take any arguments, as seen in the schema:

[image: people: [Person]]

If you're building your own schema, you can add arguments to any field, and when you implement the resolver for that field you can use the arguments for logic in that resolver.

If you're working with a schema that you don't control, you'll have to add filtering on the frontend:

```
const {people} = data.allPeople;
const brownEyedPeople = people.filter(({eyeColor}) => eyeColor === 'brown');
```

Comment: thank you i wish that was more explicit in the docs, it seemed like you could just put in arguments to any variable, which seemed nice :)

Answer (score 0):

When you start developing in Gatsby and actually pull your data into Gatsby, there will be a *filter* query option that automatically becomes available in the query arguments.

https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/graphql-reference/#filter

You can expect to be able to filter your **people** by **eyeColor** by using the below query:

```
{
  allPeople(filter: { eyeColor: { eq: "brown" } }) {
    edges {
      node {
        id
        name
        birthYear
        eyeColor
      }
    }
  }
}
```